# Basic input filename parsing in R

Tags: r, parsing

I have log files in a directory and I want to generate graphs from each of them. I have written R functions to plot graphs and save in jpg files. My CSV files are named as "_Par1_Par2_Par3_date.log" Is there any way I can get the Par1, Par2 and Par3 values inside the R code to use for some calculations? They are all integers, if that helps. I would like to take all files and generate graphs in a single command vs giving single commands for each of the 100 or so files.

Answer (score 1):

Once you read in all of the files you want, you can use something like `str_extract()` or `str_extract_all` with pattern matching from the `stringr` package to pull out the items from the file name:

```
> teststring <- "_2342_2773_23452_date.log"
> library(stringr)
> str_extract_all(teststring, "([0-9]+)")

[[1]]
[1] "2342"  "2773"  "23452"

> str_extract_all(teststring, "([0-9]+)")[[1]][1]

[1] "2342"
```

Then you could just read those values into a data frame and then do your charts from there.

Answer (score 0):

Of course.

Use

```
 path <- file.path(root, dir1, dir2)   # portable
 files <- list.files(path, pattern="*_Par1_Par2_Par3_date.log", full.names=TRUE)
```

to get a list of filenames matching your patterm.

Then use text processing (`grep`, `gsub`, `strsplit`, ...) to extract the components.  For each of those functions, StackOverflow has lots of examples.  As do the manual pages...